# Determine Max Addressable Memory in PCL

Tags: .net, math, memory, portable-class-library

In a .NET library ([Deveel Math](http://github.com/deveel/deveel-math)) I'm implementing math operations over Big Decimal numbers and for one specific operation (x^10) I'm safely checking is this would cause passing the maximum addressable memory, by checking the current `Process`.

```
long byteArraySize = 1 + (long)(exp / 2.4082399653118496);
if (byteArraySize > System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PeakVirtualMemorySize64)
            // power of ten too big
            throw new ArithmeticException();
```

I'm trying to port this library to PCL model (Portable Class Library), but the profile doesn't support `System.Diagnostics.Process` class, hence I cannot determine the peak memory.

Do you know of any alternative?

**Update:**
In response to a comment: I've already tried applying a solution that catches `OutOfMemoryException` catch solution, but this happens way far in the execution, killing the process only after minutes of computation.
To be clearer, this library is straight port of a Google project, and even in the original code this trap was applied to prevent such situations. Also, this case is explicitly tested to be assess the exception is thrown before the process goes on.

Comment: The code is utter nonsense, just don't port it at all and delete it.  You already get a perfectly good OutOfMemoryException without helping, it doesn't have any bugs like this code does.  Outcome is the same, the user can't finish what he wanted to do.  If you want to set a reasonable upper limit then use 90 megabytes if IntPtr.Size equals 4.

Comment: Assertive comment, without knowing I already tried applying OutOfMemoryException: the problem with it is that on such huge scales this exception is reached after minutes of computation and exhausting the memory. I want a "fail fast" condition that prevents such situations